# Consecutive Liaisons

Tags: liaisons

Is it correct to make two liaisons in a row? For example:

*troi**s** **é**tat**s i**ndépendants*

*pa**s a**sse**z u**tile* (given that the optional liaison after pas is made)

Haven't heard such liaisons but neither have I come across such examples under liaisons interdites.

Comment: [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3550) has examples that would imply that it is possible in at least some situations. That’s also what I would expect, although I’m having trouble thinking of a set of examples diverse enough that I can extrapolate more exact rules from it.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I've got my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can occur, and I am not aware of any special status for this situation compared to considering the liaisons independently. An example is with the preverbal pronoun *en* as in *On vous en a parlé.*

Liaisons after plural nouns are usually optional if not forbidden, but in certain fixed names such as “États-Unis”, liaison almost always occurs. If you have “les États-Unis“, that makes two liaisons in a row. Other examples can be found in this paper: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/200783293.pdf

Comment: I hear “les États-Unis" quite a lot. With the double liaison, that is. Appreciate your help.

Comment: _États-Unis_ est aussi un mot composé et la liaison s'effectue aussi là la plupart du temps...